# When polynomial is power

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

$P(x)$ ia a polynomial with real coefficients, and  $k>1$ is an integer.  For any $n\in\Bbb Z$, we have $P(n)=m^k$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$. Show that there exists a real coefficients polynomial $H(x)$ such that $P(x)=(H(x))^k$, and $\forall n\in\Bbb Z,$  $H(n)$ is an integer.

This is an old question, but I never saw  a complete proof. Thanks  a lot!

Comment: http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/poly2.pdf proves this for $k=2$ but for polynomials in any number of variables. It mentions the result you want, but gives no references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is Corollary 3.3 in [this paper](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/polys.pdf).

Comment: You can skip the nonelementary stuff in §2: To arrive at corollary 3.3, you need only read up to lemma 1.5 and then §3.